# Why do Rails STI subclasses appear to persist after I change their models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sti

I've got a rails model called `Question` set up as STI (ie the migration included a `type` attribute).

My model code for `Question` is in a file called `base.rb` in folder `models/question/`, and looks like this:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid

  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :answers
end
```

I have a few subclasses (ie the STI types) of questions. For example, in the same folder, I have a file called `text.rb`:

```
class Text < Question

end
```

Here is the weird thing: it *used to* be:

```
class TextQuestion < Question

end
```

.. but I changed it today, and it is definitely, 100% saved as the former.

In the console when I run:

```
Question.subclasses.map { |c| c.name }
```

I expected to get an array that included `Text`, and no longer included `TextQuestion`. However, I get **both**!

I've reset my database locally and reloaded the console.

Any idea why I'm still seeing `TextQuestion` as a subclass of `Question`?

Comment: Search your entire project directory for "TextQuestion" and see if it exists somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, unfortunately it does not exist anywhere.

Comment: Did you reload your console by executing reload! or by exiting?

Comment: I tried both `reload!` and exiting and re-launching the console

Answer (score 1):

Remember that STI type data is stored in a column in your database called `type`. If you rename a subclass you'll have to create a migration to either delete all the old subclass instances that are in the database or rename them accordingly.

For example:

```
execute("UPDATE questions SET type='Text' WHERE type='TextQuestion'")
```

Of course adjust that to whatever SQL dialect you're using.

I think these phantoms you're seeing are produced by ActiveRecord since it's going to instantiate a record as whatever the `type` column indicates, even if that's wrong.

Comment: If this was the case, shouldn't a `rake db:reset` have cleared all the "phantoms"?

Comment: It should have if it deleted your table and you don't have anything in it afterwards. `db/seeds.rb` might repopulate this. There might be fixture data as well in your test environment. Can you find any reference to `TextQuestion` in your source?

Comment: It's also worth noting that `reload!` in the console may not clear out any previously defined classes. You may need to kill that off and open it again. If you change the source it will reload it, but if you remove a source file it doesn't automatically undefine the class.

Comment: Unfortunately, `rake db:reset` did not clear the phantoms.  
I tried both `reload!` and exiting and re-launching the console - neither changed the results. `db/seeds.rb` is empty, and searching for the phrase `TextQuestion` turns up no results.

Comment: It's got to be defined somewhere, so I'm curious where these are coming from. If this turns into a murder mystery type of thing, defining `self.subclassed(subclass)` on `Question` with `Rails.logger.debug(caller.inspect)` could be educational.